# Create and Call an Empty Function

Tags: c++, function, templates

Given a function signature (e.g. from a `template` argument), I want to create a (non-inlined) function with that signature, then call it.

The following should clarify this intent.  As-written, it is not valid, since the marked line actually generates a null function pointer, not an empty function:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    Function fn_trivial = {}; //incorrect; should be empty function, not null function
    fn_trivial(args...);
}
```

How can I create a function object here?

---

<sup>(Sidenote: this might seem like a weird thing to do.  The reason is it's a general-purpose profiler that calls a (marked non-inline-able) test function `n` times to compute an average latency.  A (better) semblance of the test code's cost can be obtained by subtracting the latency of a function call with the same arguments, that does nothing, in the average.)</sup>

Comment: `Function` is most likely going to be a f-pointer in which case that initialization sets it to `nullptr`. What should an "empty" function do?

Comment: concerning your sidenote: If the function does nothing then its call is a good candidate to be optimized away

Comment: @SombreroChicken OP means a NOP most probably.

Comment: Make it a local lambda and call that.

Comment: Should the trivial function return `void`? In any case, your use case is probably outside of what the C++ standard was written for (since you are actively fighting the compiler to not optimize away the call). Maybe you should figure out what the desired assembly looks like and work from there.

Comment: While initially I didn't specify, I think returning a value-initialized return type is the only sensible/correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a local function in C++.  You could create a local object type and define/call its `operator()`, or use a lambda—but at that point you might as well put it outside as a real function:

```
template <typename TypeRet, typename... Args>
TypeRet empty_function(Args... args) {
    return TypeRet();
}

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    empty_function<decltype( std::declval<Function>()(args...) )>(args...);
}
```

(Consider also adding `std::forward`, as-desired.)

Note that any worthwhile compiler will remove the call, even if it is marked as not-inline-able.  This is because even though the function is not inlined, it does nothing, and so can be elided entirely.  You can work around this in several ways, but using a `volatile` variable is portable to Clang, GCC, ICC, and MSVC:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define NOINLINE __declspec(noinline)
#else
    #define NOINLINE __attribute__((noinline))
#endif
template <typename TypeRet, typename... Args>
NOINLINE TypeRet empty_function(Args... args) {
    TypeRet volatile a = TypeRet();
    return a;
}
```

[See it live.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/JUIYF_)

Comment: @Quentin fixed. Although I just realized lambda would be way easier, so I will add this as well.

Comment: I significantly revised your answer to fix some problems, add some explanatory text, and demonstrate a workaround for the non-inline-able issue. Then I accepted it.